Why doesn't macro function work correctly to get only the needed column from a super data type attribute
I have a properties column in redshift, datatype super, which looks like this:
{"a":"a","b":"b"......."c":"c"}
I want to create a macro that can easily extract any given column from the properties.
I created this Macro:
{% macro cast_and_trim(field_name) %}

   TRIM('"' FROM cast(properties.field_name AS varchar))

{% endmacro %}

And I called it as below:
select 
id
, properties
,  {{ cast_and_trim('"Is New User"') }} AS new_user
FROM {{ ref("stg_table_name") }} 

In the end, the new model created as a view will have a new_user column completely Null, even why there are data in the properties.
I tried the code I already have shown in the description, and I was expected a new column called new_user with the same data as in the properties field.

since that looks like a JSON format, have you tried this function? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

thank you for your suggestion, but it is not json format, it is super datatype

the super datatype can contain JSON formats: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html
